# how do I conduct operations on a passed in double then return that in Java

Tags: java, return, parameter-passing

main method of file:
main issue is that double celciusToFahrenheit and the like don't return the calculated result after data is passed in and it's a constant flow like I want to return to main and have the user be prompted again for input and scale selection which is a switch case statement that outputs scale info based on the selection which is passed into inpuTemp yet even that won't output

```
public double inputTemp(int scale) {
    Scanner localInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter temperature to convert \n" 
+ "please numeric data only");
        double celciusToFahrenheitCall = cToF(inputField.nextDouble());
        double kelvinToCelciusCall = kToC(inputField.nextDouble());
        double fahrenheitToCelciusCall = fToC(inputField.nextDouble());
        double kelvinToFahrenheitCall = kToF(inputField.nextDouble());
        double celciusToKelvinCall = cToK(inputField.nextDouble());
        double fahrenheitToKelvinCall = fToK(inputField.nextDouble());
        return scale;
    }
double cToF(double inputField) {
        inputField = (9/5 * inputField + 32);
        return inputField;
        //converts Celsius to Fahrenheit and returns the answer
    }
    double kToF(double inputField) {
        double kelvinToFahrenheit = (9/5 * inputField - 273 + 32);
        return kelvinToFahrenheit;
        //converts Kelvin to Fahrenheit and returns the answer
    }
    double fToC(double inputField) {
        return (5/9 * (inputField - 32));
        //converts Fahrenheit to Celsius and returns the answer
    }
    double cToK(double inputField) {  
        return (inputField + 273);
        //converts Celsius to Kelvin and returns the answer
    }
    double kToC(double inputField) {
        return (inputField - 273);
            //converts Kelvin to Celsius and returns the answer
    }
    double fToK(double inputField) {
        return ((5/9 * (inputField -32 ) + 273));
          //converts Fahrenheit to Kelvin and returns the answer
    }
```

}

Comment: Do you realize that every time you write `inputField.nextDouble()` the program will stop and wait for the user to type another number?  If all the conversion calls inside of `inputTemp` are supposed to perform different conversions on a single input number, write `inputField.nextDouble()` **once**, assign the result to a variable, and pass the variable as arguments to the conversion calls.

Comment: thank you, that makes sense. So are you saying that:

Comment: public double inputTemp(int scale) {
        System.out.println("enter temperature to convert \n" 
+ "please numeric data only");
        double celciusToFahrenheitCall = cToF(inputField.nextDouble());
        double kelvinToCelciusCall = kToC(inputField.nextDouble());
        double fahrenheitToCelciusCall = fToC(inputField.nextDouble());
        double kelvinToFahrenheitCall = kToF(inputField.nextDouble());
        double celciusToKelvinCall = cToK(inputField.nextDouble());
        
        should say double result = inputField.nextDouble(); then pass those on the right side of =?

Comment: double result = inputField.nextDouble();
  double celciusToFahrenheitCall = cToF(result);
  double kelvinToCelciusCall = kToC(result);
  double fahrenheitToCelciusCall = fToC(result);
  double kelvinToFahrenheitCall = kToF(result);
  double celciusToKelvinCall = cToK(result);
  double fahrenheitToKelvinCall = fToK(result); although for some reason inside the method of one of these functions I get System.out.println("celcius temperature is " + fahrenheitToCelcius);
  
   double resultBlob = result.nextDouble(); cannot invoke on primitive type double

Comment: Exactly.  Not having all those mysterious extra pauses in execution will, among other things, make it a lot easier for you to work out the proper overall flow of the program (:-))